# Multipath to a logical volume in a staging VM

Tags: lvm, vmware, storage, scsi, multipath-storage

How do I configure multipath in testing VM (purpose is purely academical)?

I made new logical volume, modified `multipath.conf` to be as follows:

```
defaults {
    udev_dir         /dev
    user_friendly_names  yes
}

blacklist {
}

blacklist_exceptions {
    device {
        vendor "VMware,"
        product "VMware Virtual S"
    }
}
```

and `multipath -v3` says:

```
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: rev = 1.0
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: h:b:t:l = 2:0:1:0
Apr 22 03:22:24 | (null): (VMware,:VMware Virtual S) vendor/product whitelisted
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: serial = 
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: get_state
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: path checker = directio (config file default)
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: checker timeout = 180000 ms (sysfs setting)
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: state = running
Apr 22 03:22:24 | directio: starting new request
Apr 22 03:22:24 | directio: io finished 4096/0
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: state = 3
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: getuid = /lib/udev/scsi_id --whitelisted --device=/dev/%n (config file default)
Apr 22 03:22:24 | /lib/udev/scsi_id exitted with 1
Apr 22 03:22:24 | error calling out /lib/udev/scsi_id --whitelisted --device=/dev/sdb
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: state = running
Apr 22 03:22:24 | /lib/udev/scsi_id exitted with 1
Apr 22 03:22:24 | error calling out /lib/udev/scsi_id --whitelisted --device=/dev/sdb
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: detect_prio = 1 (config file default)
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: prio = const (config file default)
Apr 22 03:22:24 | sdb: const prio = 1
Apr 22 03:22:24 | dm-0: device node name blacklisted
Apr 22 03:22:24 | dm-1: device node name blacklisted
Apr 22 03:22:24 | dm-2: device node name blacklisted
===== paths list =====
uuid hcil    dev dev_t pri dm_st chk_st vend/prod/rev            dev_st 
     2:0:0:0 sda 8:0   1   undef ready  VMware,,VMware Virtual S running
     2:0:1:0 sdb 8:16  1   undef ready  VMware,,VMware Virtual S running
[root@localhost ~]#
```

I want to configure multipath for logical volume on `/dev/sdb`.

My blacklist is empty, why does it say that `dm-0/1/2` are blacklisted?

Also, when I run `lib/udev/scsi_id --whitelisted --device=/dev` manually I got no errors. no output or changes either, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
multipathd -k 
show config
```

On my system it seems that an empty blacklist is ignored and it contains, in addition to vendors blacklisted devices, these devnodes paterns:

```
devnode "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"
devnode "^hd[a-z]"
devnode "^dcssblk[0-9]*"
```

It matches "dm-"

you could try to add the "dm-1, dm-2 .. " devnodes into the blacklist exception. I never tried. I don't know the impact if you put an exception on a multipath dm file for instance.